# $f_n(x) = \dfrac{nx^2 + 1}{2n + x}$, assume $f_n$ converges to $f$ and $f'_n$ converges to $g$ pointwisely. Then $f' = g$ on a compact subset of reals

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I showed that $f_n$ converges to some $f$ uniformly. Now I need to show that $f'_n$ converges to $g$ uniformly such that $g=f′$, but I do not know how to show it. Because I want to utilize the following theorem: Let $f_n:[,] \to ℝ$ be a sequence of differentiable functions whose derivatives $f'_n$ are continuous. If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $f'_n$ converges uniformly to $g$, then the limit $f$ is differentiable, and its derivative is $′=$

Comment: Very confusing. What you asked for in the title is something you say you already know as a theorem. What exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: @geetha290krm I cannot show that $f'_n$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: @geetha290krm - The question is about uniform convergence in a compact set, so there is no problem - all but finitely many of the sequence terms is well defined.

Comment: @Hypatia - Differentiate $f_n(x)$, compute the limit as $n\to\infty$ for a fixed $x$, it will be something that depends on $x$, of course, say, some $g(x)$. Then consider the difference $|(f_n)'(x)-g(x)|$ and prove that the supremum over any finite interval tends to zero.

Comment: You will need the fact that $2n+x>n$ for all $x$ in a compact set if $n$ is large enough.

Comment: If it helps, $|f_n'(x)-f'(x)|=|\frac{x^3+3nx^2+1}{x^2+4nx+4n^2}|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out, you can show this directly. You already showed that $f_n(x) \to \frac 12 x^2$, uniformly on $[a,b]$. So, you just need to verify that
$$
\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f'_n(x)-x| \to 0 \quad(n \to \infty),
$$
which is true, since
\begin{align*}
|f'_n(x)-x| = \frac{|3 n x^2+x^3+1|}{(2 n+x)^2} = \frac{n(3x^2+x^3/n+1/n)}{n^2(x^2/n^2+4x/n+4)} \to 0 \quad (n\to \infty, x \in [a,b]).
\end{align*}